# Microsoft Sync Framework two ways synchronization issue

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm trying to use Microsoft sync framework to synchronize data between two SQl servers data base,but it's sync in one way only, any Suggestions?

```
 SqlSyncProvider sqlProviderLocal = new SqlSyncProvider(downloadScope, sqlConnLocal);
        SqlSyncProvider sqlProviderRemote = new SqlSyncProvider(downloadScope, sqlConnRemote);
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning scopeProvisionLocal = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnLocal);
        SqlSyncScopeProvisioning scopeProvisionRemote = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(sqlConnRemote);
        scopeProvisionLocal.ObjectSchema = ".dbo";
        scopeProvisionRemote.ObjectSchema = ".dbo";
        string[] tablesToSync = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SyncTablesDownloadFromRemote"].Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        if (!scopeProvisionLocal.ScopeExists(downloadScope))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = new DbSyncScopeDescription(downloadScope);

            for (int i = 0; i < Tables.Length; i++)
            {

                scopeDesc.Tables.Add(SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForTable(Tables[i], sqlConnLocal));
            }

            scopeProvisionLocal.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            scopeProvisionLocal.SetCreateTableDefault(DbSyncCreationOption.Skip);
            scopeProvisionLocal.Apply();
        }

        if (!scopeProvisionRemote.ScopeExists(downloadScope))
        {
            DbSyncScopeDescription scopeDesc = SqlSyncDescriptionBuilder.GetDescriptionForScope(downloadScope, sqlConnLocal);
            scopeProvisionRemote.PopulateFromScopeDescription(scopeDesc);
            scopeProvisionRemote.Apply();
        }

        agent.LocalProvider = sqlProviderLocal;
        agent.RemoteProvider = sqlProviderRemote;


        agent.Direction = SyncDirectionOrder.DownloadAndUpload;
        SyncOperationStatistics Uploadstats = agent.Synchronize();
```

Comment: can you describe what the actual sync behaviour is? are you getting error? are you seeing changes that should have been synched but is not?

Comment: each piece of code run correctly, but the result is the data synchronized only from source to destination, but not vise versa, if you note I determined the direction to be Download And Upload

Comment: can you enable sync fx tracing to log the actual sync activities? or handle the event and put a breakpoint on ChangesSelected on both providers and see if change are actually detected. If changes are detected, have a look at ApplyChangesFailed event if there are errors/conflicts detected applying changes.